# Coupon creating using child product of a Configurable products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to create a coupon using variance of a configurable product.Suppose,i have  configurable product(Cp-01),it have three child simple products. Color of product is red,green,blue consequentially. I have create a coupon it will apply when size red and sku is Cp-01 .Please help me[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SKU of the child product, i.e. the red one in you case.

1. Open the configurable product (Cp-01).
2. Go to `Associated Products` tab.
3. Check the product ID of the simple product (e.g. 123).
4. Use the SKU which is related to this ID (123) in the coupon.

Comment: I have attached a image .please check enenen